# How to align string contents text in a listbox?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, string-formatting

I'm having a problem aligning string contents in a listbox. Here's a distilled example that demonstrates the problem my app is having:

Basic XAML UI:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="687" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="lstClients" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="28,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="625"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
Class MainWindow
    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim names() As String = {"Cook, Adam", "Renolds, Bridgette", "Smith, Carla", "Doe, Daniel",
                                "Redmond, Ebenezer", "Kelly, Francine"}
        Dim ids() As String = {"123456", "654321", "112345", "274587", "128493", "937401"}
        Dim dob() As String = {"1/2/80", "4/17/88", "8/31/72", "6/11/91", "10/27/81", "3/3/75"}
        Dim phones() As String = {"1234567890", "2536772364", "1537779004", "7586712164", "8548778384", "0987654321"}

        For i As Integer = 0 To 5
            lstClients.Items.Add(FormatClientString(names(i), ids(i), dob(i), phones(i)))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function FormatClientString(name As String, id As String, birthDate As String, phone As String)
        Dim clientString As String
        clientString = String.Format("{0, -52} {1, -17} {2, -20} {3}", name, id, birthDate, phone)
        Return clientString
    End Function
End Class
```

Output:
[image: output]

And here is what I am actually trying to accomplish (crappy paint editing but basically I just want the columns to align, regardless of the length of the client's name):
[image: desiredOutput]

From what I read, [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) should do what I want, but the output is never right. I also tried using [String.PadRight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830(v=vs.110).aspx) for each string (names, ids, dob, and phones) but got the same behavior (misaligned columns).

Am I overlooking something simple?

**EDIT**: The control in my actual app is not a ListBox. It is an AutoCompleteBox from the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535). I used the ListBox above as an example because it was exhibiting the same behavior formatting the strings and was easier to make a simple example with.

If anyone knows how to add columns to the AutoCompleteBox's dropdown suggestions, that would work too as this is ultimately the goal.

Comment: Proportional width fonts doesn't have the same width  for each letter and space. But why don't you use a ListView instead?

Comment: @Steve In actuality it is an AutoCompleteBox from the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535) but the mis-alignment behavior is the same in a ListBox (I'm using a `List(Of String)` for the AutoCompleteBox's `ItemsSource`).

Comment: As I have said. The problem is caused by the font used by your control. It is a proportional font so you cannot create columns of a certain width using spaces to fill the missing characters. Try to set a fixed width font like Consolas and you will see the difference. The simple solution is to use a control that 'knows' what a 'multi columns' means.

Comment: I deleted my asnwer because you updated the question

Comment: @Steve You nailed it. I changed it to Consolas and it worked. Submit this as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the font used by your control. It is a proportional font so you cannot create columns of a certain width using spaces to fill the column because every line has a different length in pixels of the text part.

Setting a fixed width font like Consolas (where every character has the same width in pixels) will fix the problem.

However the fixed width font is not very pleasant to see and a better solution is to use a control that 'knows' what 'multi columns' means. (ListView, DataGrid)

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to show `string.Format` with proportional fonts, try this XAML (which is just ***for fun***, but may be used in some simple apps which don't require much flexibility in styling). Using this code, we may need to tweak the fixed `Width` depending on the chosen font:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstClients" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="28,22,0,0" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="625" FontFamily="Lucida Calligraphy">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">                        
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border Width="20" Margin="0,0,-12,0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>                                
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The idea here is each string is an array of characters. So we define an `ItemTemplate` foreach data item (a string). The template should be an `ItemsControl` to show a list of characters in a custom `ItemsPanelTemplate` to stack those characters horizontally (to join in a readable text). Because each character is a `Border` having fixed width, it can be used with any font with appropriate Width set for `Border` (and its `Margin`). For wrapping text, we may need to play with `WrapPanel` instead. But anyway it's some kind of funny trick and should not be used in important business apps.

[image]